# klocwork:Suspicious dereference of object reference 'dt' before null check

Tags: c#, klocwork

I am getting `Suspicious dereference of object reference 'dt' before null check` error with `Klocwork' code analysis. What could be the solution? Thanks!

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
        {
            dt.TableName = "Hello";
            dt.Columns.Add("HEllo1", typeof(string));
            if (dt != null)
            {
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

Getting error at below line,

`if (dt != null)`

Comment: The null check is absolutely useless. dt can not be null here.

Comment: You understand that by wrapping `DataTable` in a `using` statement means that it will be disposed of at the point where it exists the `using`? That means you will return a _disposed_ object. Furthermore you have no null check, you're simply comparing dt to null, doing nothing with the result, and then returning dt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line

```
if (dt != null)
```

obviously, checks if dt is null. From this, your analyzer assumes that dt might be null at this point. However, immediately before that, you have the following line:

```
dt.Columns.Add("HEllo1", typeof(string));
```

which would produce NullReferenceException if dt is null. 
That's why your analyzer warns you that something is wrong here: it is either dt can't be null so the null check is redundant or your code might throw a sudden NullReferenceException and you should add more null checks.